# How does a PCIe card behave when connected to fewer lanes of a higher version?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

From what I've learned about PCIe I know that as long as it fits the physical slot, a card will operate fine when the number of electrical lanes differ or when the PCIe versions mismatch, albeit at a speed that all "parties" agree on.

I'm interested in what happens in a case where both apply at the same time. Assume that the slot is physically large enough, so what I'm referring to are the electrical lanes. The slot is PCIe 3.0 x1 and the card is 2.0 x2. The single 3.0 lane has (almost) enough bandwidth to feed the two 2.0 lanes. Will the card make use of that bandwidth, or will it use the one available 3.0 lane as if it was 2.0, essentially halving the bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a slot has one lane the card can only use one lane because there is only one physical lane present in the slot.

And if the card only supports PCIe 2 then this one lane can only operate in PCIe 2 mode.

Hence if the card works at all it will operate at half speed with one single PCIe 2 lane only.